# React/Redux. Cannot intercept and override click events on nested components in main App component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to prevent all `events` on the page if one of `edit buttons` inside  nested container `TodoListAdd (his Component)` of main `component` `App` is activated.

I use **React** and **Redux** for components manipulates and state updates. And what structure I have for now:

1. Main `App` component that render all `containers` for all `components` of App;
2. 4 nested `containers` with their own `components` inside the App;
3. Each of the nested `components` have they own click event handlers.

**My algoritm to track changes (it's work!)** - I set on the main `App` component tracker-function, that updates own state due to its callback in the nested `container TodoListAdd (inside his Component)` each time, when it makes a rerender. So, in this way I has a controll over the all edit buttons that can be created in the app, and if someone of they is fired I will know about it.

**My problem** - to prevent all clicks on the page I just use the function:

```
        document.documentElement.onclick = (e) => 
              {
                    console.log('Document click!!!'); e.preventDefault(); return false
              }
```

But for some non-understandable **it prevent events** **only for first** of four `containers(and their components)` without any effect on all other adjacent `containers(and their components)`

I will be grateful for any help...

> Do not be afraided by the length of the code in my post, it is prone to an overall view. To solve the problem we can just use the first 3th iteams of code: main App comp, worked comp and non-worked comp. Thank you for your time!

/* APP */

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import TodoFormAdd from '../Containers/TodoFormAdd';
import TodoListAdd from '../Containers/TodoListAdd';
import TodoFormFilterAdd from '../Containers/TodoFormFilterAdd';
import TodoFilter from '../Containers/TodoFilter';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleUpdate = (buttonCount) => {
        buttonCount.forEach(button => {
            if (button.done === true) {
                document.documentElement.onclick = (e) => {console.log('Document click!!!'); e.preventDefault(); return false}
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <TodoFormAdd />
                <TodoListAdd handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}/>
                <TodoFormFilterAdd />
                <TodoFilter />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

/* TodoFormAdd  (his Component) **only on it I can prevent click events** */

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

class TodoForm extends React.Component{   
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log('l');

        let input = document.querySelector('input'); 
        if (input.value !== '') {
            this.props.todoFormAdd(input.value); 
            input.value = '';
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <form id="tp" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={{display:"inline-block"}}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your text" />
                    <button type="submit">Add todos</button>
                </form>
        );  
    }
}
export default TodoForm;
```

/* TodoListAdd (his Component) */

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import TodoIteam from '../TodoIteam/TodoIteam'

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    handleDelete = (e) => {
         //some logic.... (deleted to minify the view on SOF)
    }

    render(props) {
        console.log('Hi', this.props.state.iteams.buttons);
        this.props.handleUpdate(this.props.state.iteams.buttons);
        return ( 
            <Fragment>
                <div onClick={this.handleDelete} className="todo__container" >
                    {this.props.state.iteams.todos.map((iteam, index) => {
                        return <TodoIteam iteams={this.props.state.iteams.todos} buttons={this.props.state.iteams.buttons[index]} key={index} {...iteam} />
                    })}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

/* TodoFormFilterAdd (his Component) */

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

class TodoFormFilter extends React.Component{   
    handleClickUp = (e) => {
        this.props.todoFilterUp(); 
    }

    handleClickDown = (e) => {
        this.props.todoFilterDown(); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClickUp} style={{display:"inline-block"}}>SortUp todos</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClickDown} style={{display:"inline-block"}}>SortDown todos</button>
            </div>
        );  
    }
}
export default TodoFormFilter;
```

/* Todo Filter (his Component) */

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

class TodoFilter extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={(e) => {this.props.onClick(null, e.target.name)}} name={'VISIBLE_TODO_ALL'}>View All</button>
                <button onClick={(e) => {this.props.onClick(null, e.target.name)}} name={'VISIBLE_TODO_ACTIVE'}>View Active</button>
                <button onClick={(e) => {this.props.onClick(null, e.target.name)}} name={'VISIBLE_TODO_DONED'}>View Completed</button>
                <input onChange={(e) => {this.props.onClick(e.target.value, e.target.name)}} name={'VISIBLE_TODO_SEARCH'} type="text" placeholder='Type to search...'/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoFilter;
```

Comment: can you create a reproduction at [codepen](https://codepen.io) or similar service. Its a bit hard to follow..

Answer (score 2):

So, your problem in covered inside the React logic of event handlers. To make `prevent events` work in the all app you just need to use the `e.stopPropagation()`, insted of `e.preventDefault()`. If to be shortly, a such problem with prevent multiple event handlers happens, because React have some differences between **Vanilla DOM** and **React Virtual DOM** work standarts.

So just add after your:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Additional events preventer:

```
 e.stopPropagation()
```

If you are really interested to undertand why it's problem happens - see this official React doc -> https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html .